# Change XOR to XNOR

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor, bitwise-xor

I am working with a XNOR encrypted file whose key is not known. I want to modify the xortool which is available here: https://github.com/hellman/xortool to work for XNOR encryption.

Apparently, there are only two lines which uses the '^' operator. So I tried changing them to xnor using ~ operator. But I could not get the required output. How can I accomplish this?

Edit: The code uses '^' operator only in line 248 in xortool.py

```
key_possible_bytes[offset] += chr(ord(char) ^ most_char)
```

and in line 75 in routine.py

```
 ret[index] = (chr(ord(char) ^ ord(key[index % len(key)])))
```

So I added a ~ operator before both of them.

Comment: *How* did you change them? Can you include some relevant code in your post?

Comment: Do you have to change it? Finding the XNOR key is equivalent to finding the XOR key and inverting that key.

Comment: If you have both the plain-text and the cypher-text you can derive the key...

Answer (score 9):

Replace all instances of `a ^ b` with `~(a ^ b)` to change the XOR operations to XNOR operations. Be sure to insert the not operator at the correct location to ensure correct order of operations occurs!

Using Your specific code examples:

`key_possible_bytes[offset] += chr(`***`~(ord(char) ^ most_char)`***`)`

`ret[index] = (chr(`***`~(ord(char) ^ ord(key[index % len(key)]))`***`))`

Comment: Yeah, I did the same, but I get this error `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'`

Comment: `~` is the bitwise NOT operator in `C` and most other languages derive their bitwise operators from `C` syntax. According to a cursory Google search, python is not an acceptation.

Answer (score 3):

The question is aimed at bitwise operators in Python, but for those (like me) who are dealing with booleans, the above version of XNOR does *not* work as expected:

```py
In [1]: for i in [True, False]:
   ...:     for j in [True, False]:
   ...:         print(i, j, ' = ', ~(i^j))
   ...: 
True True  =  -1
True False  =  -2
False True  =  -2
False False  =  -1
```

Instead, you'll want to use `not` instead of `~`:

```py
In [2]: for i in [True, False]:
   ...:     for j in [True, False]:
   ...:         print(i, j, ' = ', not (i^j))
   ...: 
True True  =  True
True False  =  False
False True  =  False
False False  =  True
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtract from the largest value.

If you are `xoring' 8-bit values, this will do the job:

`0xff - (0xf0 ^ 0x0f)`